# IdentityServer 3 - Tokens/Cookies queries

Tags: identityserver3

So we are implementing IdentityServer3 in our system. We have most of everything implemented, but have noticed a few oddities which bring about some questions, I apologies in advance with my loose terminology as I am quite new to this. These queries are mostly related to the cookies/tokens of IDS3.

1) During a 'standard' login process, where we go from our client application - Identity Server Login - Back to our client, are both an Identity_token and Access_Token getting passed back to the client? Or does the Access_token need to be requested separately by the client application?

2)We have noticed after 5 minutes Identity Server tries to reauthorize or perform an action - is this the Access_token being refreshed or something else? We have found we can change this behavior by setting 'UseTokenLifetime = false' and then changing certain values in our cookie middleware, but we are curious as to why the Identity_token expiry time is being used here when apparently the Identity_token is only needed during the login process.

Thank You for any replies!

Comment: For Point 1: What are you specifying as `ResponseType` in your client? Your response type tells the IdSvr to return that particular response. In your case, I guess you're requesting `id_token token`.